# Android Accessibility: Move focus to the outer layout, but double-tapping triggers the click event of inner view

Tags: android, click, focus, accessibility, talkback

I am trying to make our app accessible.

Basically, we have a clickable LinearLayout with click listener. And this outer LinearLayout contains multiple views that have other click listener.

When moving the focus to the outer LinearLayout and double-tap to trigger the click listener, the inner view's click listener is triggered instead of the outer LinearLayout's.